# can't codesign the .app file using Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, macos, sqlite, code-signing, xamarin.mac

I'm developing a C# application in Visual Studio for Mac.
I have it set up to be signed with a developer ID signature to get it notarized by Apple.
But it's not working.

Here are the steps.

(1). Sign the code using Visual Studio for Mac.
(2). However, this .app file will crash.
(3). When I create a dmg and request notarization with the *xcrun altool* command, I get the following error.

```
{
  "logFormatVersion": 1,
  "jobId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "status": "Invalid",
  "statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
  "statusCode": 4000,
  "archiveFilename": "MyApp.dmg",
  "uploadDate": "2020-08-18T08:29:55Z",
  "sha256": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ticketContents": null,
  "issues": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "MyApp.dmg/MyApp.app/Contents/MonoBundle/SQLite.Interop.dll",
      "message": "The signature of the binary is invalid.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    }
  ]
}
```

Even if this succeeds, it won't matter because it will crash...
Thinking that *SQLite.Interop.dll* was the cause, I signed the code directly after step (1) and it started successfully.

```
$ codesign --force --verify --verbose \
    --sign "Developer ID Application: MyCompany (XXXXXXXXX)" \
    "SQLite.Interop.dll" \
    --deep \
    --options runtime \
    --timestamp
```

However, requesting a notarization with the *xcrun altool* command returns an error like this:

```
{
  "logFormatVersion": 1,
  "jobId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "status": "Invalid",
  "statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
  "statusCode": 4000,
  "archiveFilename": "MyApp.dmg",
  "uploadDate": "2020-08-18T08:29:55Z",
  "sha256": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "ticketContents": null,
  "issues": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "MyApp.dmg/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp",
      "message": "The signature of the binary is invalid.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    }
  ]
}
```

I thins this is due to a change in the signature of the dependency *SQLite.Interop.dll*, which has resulted in an incorrect signature in MyApp.
How can I solve this?

Here's what I've already tried.

- Manually sign *MyApp.dmg/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp* again.
- Sign *SQLite.Interop.dll* manually before the procedure (1).

Here is some information that will assist

- Settings for signing .csproj files

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <EnableCodeSigning>true</EnableCodeSigning>
    <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    <EnablePackageSigning>false</EnablePackageSigning>
    <IncludeMonoRuntime>true</IncludeMonoRuntime>
    <UseSGen>true</UseSGen>
    <UseRefCounting>true</UseRefCounting>
    <LinkMode>SdkOnly</LinkMode>
    <AOTMode>None</AOTMode>
    <CodeSigningKey>Developer ID Application: MyCompany (XXXXXXXXXXX)</CodeSigningKey>
    <PackageSigningKey>3rd Party Mac Developer Installer</PackageSigningKey>
    <UseHardenedRuntime>true</UseHardenedRuntime>
    <CodeSignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodeSignEntitlements>
    <CodeSignExtraArgs>--deep</CodeSignExtraArgs>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

- Entitlements.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm using *SQLite.Interop.dll* in *System.Data.SQLite.Core*, which I got from NuGet.

```
packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.111.0/runtimes/osx-x64/native/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.dll
```

postscript 2020/08/31 15:52:
Part of the Visual Studio for mac build log:

```
Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
    Creating directory "obj/Release/en".
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.5/al.exe /culture:en /out:obj/Release/en/MyApp.resources.dll /template:obj/Release/MyApp.exe /embed:obj/Release/improvementproductivityforMac.Resources.AppResources.en.resources
Target _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
    Copying file from "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/packages/NLog.4.6.6/lib/netstandard2.0/NLog.dll" to "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/NLog.dll".
    Copying file from "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.111.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Data.SQLite.xml" to "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/System.Data.SQLite.xml".
    Copying file from "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/packages/NLog.4.6.6/lib/netstandard2.0/NLog.xml" to "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/NLog.xml".
    Copying file from "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.111.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Data.SQLite.dll" to "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/System.Data.SQLite.dll".
    Copying file from "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.111.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Data.SQLite.dll.config" to "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/System.Data.SQLite.dll.config".
    Creating "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/obj/Release/MyApp.csproj.CopyComplete" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    Copying file from "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/obj/Release/MyApp.exe" to "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/MyApp.exe".
    MyApp -> /Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/MyApp.exe
    Copying file from "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/obj/Release/en/MyApp.resources.dll" to "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/en/MyApp.resources.dll".
Target _DetectSigningIdentity:
    Detected signing identity:
            
      Code Signing Key: "Developer ID Application: MYCOMPANY (7LM65QQ5VR)" (C34D25E1BBB78996C6A0257E78A87C103A320815)
      Bundle Id: jp.mycompany
      App Id: jp.mycompany
Target _CopyContentToBundle:
    Creating directory '/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources'
            
    ~
            
    Copying file from '/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/Resources/update.png' to '/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/update.png'
            
Target _CompileToNative:
    /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mmp @/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/obj/Release/response-file.rsp 
    MMP : warning MM0079: The recommended Xcode version for Xamarin.Mac 6.20.2 is Xcode 11.6 or later. The current Xcode version (found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer) is 11.2.
            
    MMP : warning MM2006: Native library 'libdl' was referenced but could not be found.
            
    MMP : warning MM2009: Referenced by System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethodsPosix.dlopen
            
Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "MyApp.csproj".
Target CopyOurFiles:
    This is us copying a file into resources!
    Copying file from "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/NLog.config" to "/Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/MyApp.app/Contents/MonoBundle/NLog.config".
Target _CodesignNativeLibraries:
    Tool /usr/bin/codesign execution started with arguments: -v --force --timestamp --sign C34D25E1BBB78996C6A0257E78A87C103A320815 --deep /Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/MyApp.app/Contents/MonoBundle/libmono-native.dylib
            
    Tool /usr/bin/codesign execution started with arguments: -v --force --timestamp --sign C34D25E1BBB78996C6A0257E78A87C103A320815 --deep /Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/MyApp.app/Contents/MonoBundle/libMonoPosixHelper.dylib
            
Target _CodesignAppBundle:
    Tool /usr/bin/codesign execution started with arguments: -v --force -o runtime --timestamp --sign C34D25E1BBB78996C6A0257E78A87C103A320815 --entitlements /Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/obj/Release/Entitlements.xcent --deep /Users/tomityu/Gits/my-app/MyApp/bin/Release/MyApp.app
            
Target _CodesignVerify:
    /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv --deep bin/Release/MyApp.app 
    bin/Release/MyApp.app: valid on disk
    bin/Release/MyApp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

Done building project "MyApp.csproj".

Build succeeded.
```

Comment: Are you able to view the command-line that MSBuild is invoking when it signs your application?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
Added to the text.

Comment: Your new output says you're using a much older version of XCode than is recommended (you're using 11.2 but Xamarin needs 11.6). Is there a reason you're using an older version? Perhaps updating your XCode version will make it work?

Comment: I updated the version of Xcode to 11.6 and tried again, but the result was the same.
The app crashes in step (2).

Comment: Can anyone help me solve this problem?